# Matrix Representation of an Operator (Volterra)

Tags: functional-analysis

Generally, how can I find the matrix of a given operator $K$ with respect to a given basis ${e_n}$?

I thought I should use $\langle K(e_n),e_m\rangle$, is it the right way?

In particular, how can I find the matrix representation of Volterra operator, i.e $K(\varphi)=\int_{a}^{b}k(t-s)\varphi(s)ds$? Is there easier way than the way I proposed?